# Change $(this) input field color based on class effecting all classes in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML that occurs multiple times on a page:

```
<div class="canteen-item">
    <div class="col-l">
        <h4>Chicken Sandwich</h4>
        <p>$<span class="canteen-price">3.50</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-r">
        <div class="qty-days">
            <input name="Mon" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
            <input name="Tue" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
            <input name="Wed" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
            <input name="Thu" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
            <input name="Fri" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this JQuery to detect when the input field is changed and if the value is greater than 0, change the color to red.

```
$(".qty-input").change(function(){
    var qty = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(qty > 0){
        $(this).css('color','red');
    }
    else{
        $(this).css('color','black');
    }
});
```

It is behaving very unpredictably. When I change the value of the first input field (Monday), it makes all 5 inputs red. Then sometimes it is changing the colors back to black in completely different rows sets of days. Seems like a simple problem to fix, but having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Are you duplicating IDs when you repeat that block of HTML?

Comment: Post code that reproduces the issue. Your code works fine as it is.

Comment: I've tested too and it seems to work fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0bg7bq5t/ working fine!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0bg7bq5t/1/ seems to work fine when duplicating ID's as well, not sure what your issue is...

Comment: Check out `<input type="number" max="0">`, you might not need any javascript at all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this code:

```
var qty = $(this).val();
```

Returns a string. And this code compares that string to a Number

```
if(qty > 0){
```

Try changing the first line of code to:

```
if ($(this).val()) {
    var qty = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
}
```

And it should start to work more consistently but you will also want to validate that the input is all numbers.

Comment: I initially had
    var qty = parseInt($(this).val()); ... but that was not making a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use change event target to get to the element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".qty-input").change(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    var qty = $(target).val();
    if (qty > 0) {
      $(target).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
      $(target).css('color', 'black');
    }
    alert("value is " + qty)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canteen-item">
  <div class="col-l">
    <h4>Chicken Sandwich</h4>
    <p>$<span class="canteen-price">3.50</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-r">
    <div class="qty-days">
      <input type="text" name="Mon" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
      <input type="text" name="Tue" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
      <input type="text" name="Wed" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
      <input type="text" name="Thu" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
      <input type="text" name="Fri" class="qty-input" value="0" maxlength="2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This made no difference. Same problem.

Comment: Opps - forget to reference the target later on

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. It prompted me to dig deeper at which point I discovered another piece of code in a different JS file that was trying (incorrectly!) to do the same thing. The code I have above is in fact sound and works perfectly. I apologize for wasting anyone's time here. I didn't realize that my client had a developer who had already attempted to do this (and who also put the code in the wrong file).